# How to separate audio from video without converting into a file?

Tags: java, audio, vlcj, xuggle

googled and found some libraries like xuggle, vlcj and how to convert video to audio. But I want to stream audio without making it as a separate audio file using java. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Comment: Can Any one tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use vlcj for it even though it feels like a strange way to go since it's a library created for video playback.. but if you just don't set a video surface then it might play only the audio.. not sure if it's possible through the embeddedmediaplayercomponent but it should be possible if using the DirectMediaPlayerComponent.